# How can i improve my if-else construction

Tags: javascript

I didn't know how to make code more beautiful. I need to make return into my app, it's just recomendations for user. And i make like this, but maybe you can improve it:

```
  const makeRecomendations = (wordsPerMinute, newAverage) => {
    if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <=8) && output.length < 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && newAverage <=5 && output.length < 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nГоворите громче'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && newAverage >=8 && output.length < 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nГоворите тише'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && (newAverage >=8) && output.length >= 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nГоворите тише\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && (newAverage <=5) && output.length >= 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nГоворите громче\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <=8) && output.length >= 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  >= 180 && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <=8) && output.length < 1) return 'Не торопитесь во время доклада'
    else if ((wordsPerMinute >= 119 && wordsPerMinute <= 180)  && newAverage <=5 && output.length < 1) return 'Говорите громче'
    else if ((wordsPerMinute >= 119 && wordsPerMinute <= 180)  && newAverage >=8 && output.length < 1) return 'Говорите тише'
    else if ((wordsPerMinute >= 119 && wordsPerMinute <= 180)  && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <= 8) && output.length >= 1) return 'Контролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if ((wordsPerMinute >= 119 && wordsPerMinute <= 180)  && newAverage <=5 &&  output.length >= 1) return 'Говорите громче\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute >=180  && newAverage <=5 &&  output.length >= 1) return 'Не торопитесь во время доклада\nГоворите громче\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute >=180  && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <= 8) &&  output.length < 1) return 'Не торопитесь во время доклада'
    else if (wordsPerMinute >=180  && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <= 8) &&  output.length >= 1) return 'Не торопитесь во время доклада\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute <= 119  && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <= 8) &&  output.length >= 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи'
    else return "Вы потрясающий спикер!"

  }
```

Comment: Try strategy pattern, or object map, or switch, or leave it as-is ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: Please add the return values in English or post this question in [ru.so]. It's hard to tell if those messages could be grouped.

Comment: Also, where is `output` defined? As it stands my only real recommendation for this is to declare a variable to return, and set that variable to the appropriate message and, further, the use of `{...}` and new-lines would aid readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest nesting your if statements and declaring variables since you use the same conditions a lot.

```js
// declare commonly used variables
let sNewAvg = newAverage <=5 // small new average
let mNewAvg = newAverage <=8 // medium new average
let sOut = output.length < 1 // small output
let bOut = output.length >= 1 // big output
// wpm = wordsPerMinute
if (wpm <= 119) { 
  // everything smaller than 119
  if (sNewAvg && sOut) {
    return "..."
  } else if (mNewAvg && sOut) {
    return "..."
  } else {
    return "..."
  }
  // etc
} else if (wpm <= 180) {
  // everything between 119 and 180
} else {
  // everything bigger than 180
}
```

Comment: no need for `else`. just go on with `if`.